# C# WPF meaning of a certain description message

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

> removes a first occurrence of a specific object

I simply cannot understand this. (when removing of a ListView an item)

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot understand this"? Do you mean you do not understand how to remove an object from a `ListView`? Do you mean you don't understand what it'll do when you attempt to remove an `object`? Can you expand on how you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe use `list.Remove(object)` and give index there. Maybe you want use `list.RemoveAt(index)`
This will remove the first occurance of the object in a list:

```
list.Remove(object)
```

This will remove a specific element:

```
list.RemoveAt(index)
```

If you give code from your removing will be fine.